# Why the output is -120?

Tags: java

This is the code:

```
public class Boy {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = 12;

        System.out.print(i += i -= i *= i);
    }
}
```

Why the output is -120,how to see the executing detail?What is the step by step procedure?

Comment: Step by Step would be to write the operators out.

Comment: SO is not here to do your homeworks for you.

Comment: yes............

Comment: @MuratK. I just can't figure out what is the step.

Comment: Start from [the official tutorial about operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html).

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_basic_operators.htm

Comment: Math expressions are executed by operator precedence. So if you take that into account along with the fact that operator is executed before assignment, the term is `12 + 12 - (12 * 12)`. What's the result of that?

Comment: If you want a certain order use parentheses.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are the three things you need to know :

1. Expressions are evaluated from left to right.
2. The 2 operands of a binary operator are evaluated before the operator is applied.
3. In a complex assignment operator (such as +=,-=,*=), the original value of the left operand (the one you are assigning the result to) is stored before the operation is performed.

Now let's evaluate

```
i += i -= i *= i
```

The first operator is +=. Its first operand is 12 and its second operand - `i -= i *= i` - must be evaluated before we can evaluate +=

So we move to evaluate

```
i -= i *= i
```

The first operand is 12 and the second is `i *= i`. We must evaluate that second operand before we can evaluate -=

We move to

```
i *= i
```

The first operand is 12 and the second operand is 12, so we get 144.

Now back to

```
i -= 144
```

As you recall, the first operand was 12, so we get 12 - 144 = -132.

Now back to

```
i += -132
```

The first operand was 12, so we get 12 + -132 = -120, which is the final value assigned to i.

Comment: Thank you Eran for the proper answer.

Comment: Thank you for you patient.@Eran